# ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file ordirectory

Tags: arduino

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "YourAuthToken";

// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "YourNetworkName";
char pass[] = "YourPassword";

 void setup()
{
 // Debug console
 Serial.begin(9600);

 Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
 }

 void loop()
 {
 Blynk.run();
 }
```

---

i am using a esp8266 to connect to aurdino.
this is the simple program for esp8266. it is showing th error the wifi.h file directory is not found. please help me to fix this issue. i

Answer (score 0):

To use the ESP8266 or even ESP32, you might download the board package. For that, you could go to Board Manager and search ESP8266 and download the package.

```
Tools > Board > Board Manager
```

After that you will be able to use all the libraries needed. The `wifi.h` is part of the main library.